# Dryer works. Just not on my 240v circuit

Tags: dryer, 240v

Been racking my Brain. had a dryer go out on me. t/s the dryer i.e thermal fuse. switches etc. even put D.M.M. on motor leads and spun motor and it produced voltage. At a loss I purchased a used dryer form a scratch and dent store. took it home and had the same results. Dryer did not work. Took back to store for an exchange. they plugged it in and it worked just fine. ????????. when back home and started over with T/S 240v circuit. Plug had power. pulled plug, good contact. replaced breaker. and physically confirmed correct wire (30 amp ) and that it was dedicated. I ended up pulling the dryer out to the breaker panel and came directly off breaker to dryer. still not working. I am at a total loss. Any ideas would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What make and model is the breaker panel?  Have you tried throwing the handle on the dryer breaker to OFF and back ON to ensure it's reset if it ever tripped?

Comment: Please post a picture of the receptacle you are plugging into, ideally also the backside with the wires.  I'm particularly interested in whether neutral is hooked up properly.